# Can we access the objects we created in ruby using their object _ids in ruby?

Tags: ruby, objectid

How are the object IDs assigned in Ruby? Do some objects have fixed object_id? Can we access them using their object _ids?

Comment: You can just set variables equal to your objects and access them that way., i.e. x = Object.new.  Then just call 'x' to access the object.

Comment: What is the difference between Id, object_id, and _id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How an object ID is “assigned” depends on the Ruby implementation and other factors like the OS bitness. For example, in [CRuby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI) `nil.object_id` returns `4` on 32-bit and `8` on 64-bit.

Additionally `nil` is a so called immediate value. `true`, `false`, fixnums (small integers) and sometimes even floats are other immediate values. They have fixed IDs for the following reasons:

- they're passed by value and not by reference like the other (dynamically allocated) objects
- there's only one `nil`, one `true`, one `19`, etc. however there can be two different arrays

See the documentation of [`BasicObject#object_id`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-__id__). You can also click to toggle the source to get a look at the CRuby implementation.

Call [`ObjectSpace._id2ref`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-_id2ref) to retrieve an object by ID:

```
id = nil.object_id
ObjectSpace._id2ref(id) # => nil
```

In some implementations that method may not be implemented or really slow. [According to matz](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/348861) it was originally a hack needed to implement [`weakref`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ca9654114920982b7603e28d6e8d808df77f1795/lib/weakref.rb#L68) but current versions don't call it [anymore](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/df058ea0e3e13ad52fd3a3490b1e3bd56db044b2).

Comment: what do you mean by `immediate values`? Also if `object_ids` are fixed for `1, 2 ...` etc. So do they always exist in memory. If yes, wouldn't there be any performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

> How are the object IDs assigned in Ruby?

The Ruby Language Specification doesn't say anything about how IDs are assigned, only that

- an object has to have the same ID over its lifetime
- no two objects can have the same ID at the same time

Note that this doesn't prohibit that two different objects may have the same ID at different times, i.e. it is allowed to reuse IDs.

> Do some objects have fixed object_id?

The Ruby Language Specification doesn't say anything about how IDs are assigned. On some Ruby Implementations some objects may or may not have fixed IDs.

> Can we access them using their object _ids?

On some implementations, there is a method called `ObjectSpace::_id2ref`, but this method is not guaranteed to exist on all implementations, and it may be really expensive and on some implementations must be explicitly enabled with a command line switch.

Comment: i was just exploring thing on irb and i found out that the integers have fixed object_id with (2*i + 1) pattern. where i is integer.

Comment: There is no Ruby implementation where integers have fixed IDs. There are some Ruby implementations where `Fixnum`s have fixed IDs, but that is a private internal implementation details of those specific Ruby implementations and is not guaranteed by the Ruby Language Specification, is not necessarily true for other Ruby implementations and is, in fact, not even guaranteed to be true for future versions of that implementation, i.e. it may change at any time without notice.